# Why is my structure receiving a integer value (character) and not a pointer (string)?

Tags: c, data-structures, c-strings

**Background Information**

This is for a lab-assignment. The goal is to write a program to take in a file and store the information in a structure--then later print the elements of the structure. (Learning how to pass to and from structures) -- (C-Programming)

**File Format:**

```
CSCI112 Programming with C 3               
CSCI127 Joy and Beauty of Data 4                
COMX112 Interpersonal Skills in the Workplace 1           
HSTA101 American History 4           
XXXXXXX XXXXXX X
```

***My Problem:***  When I pass in my variable "class" or "name" into the structure it is giving me the error it is an integer. However, when I run a print statement of class  or name before the structure declaration it is a string? How is my class and name strings becoming just one character?

My structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char classes[80];
    char names[80];
    int credits;
} uni_t;
```

My main:

```
 int main() {
     char *c = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
     process_file(c);
     return (0); 
 }
```

My function that takes in file and sends words to the structures in the structure arrays:

```
void process_file(char *c){

    //Declare variables
    char *cp;
    char *bp;
    char *array[5000];
    char name[80]; //Tried to declare memory this way
    char *class = malloc(sizeof(char)*80); //And this way
    int count2 = 0;
    uni_t uni_array[300];

    //Read in file line by line
    while (fgets(c, 80, stdin) != NULL){
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;

        //Reset name/class every new line
        strcpy(name, "");
        strcpy(class, "");

        //Declare a copy of c as strtok() messes with input
        bp = c;

        //Separate each word on input line into an array
        while(1) {
            cp = strtok(bp, " \n");
            bp = NULL;
            if (cp == NULL){
                break;
            }
            array[count] = cp; 
            count++;
        }

        //Create Name
        for (i = 1 ; i < count-1; ++i){
            strcat(name, array[i]);
            strcat(name, " ");
        }

        //Create Class
        strcat(class, array[0]);
        printf("Class: %s\n", class); //This is giving me right value

        //Pass in structures 

        //Structure declaration (Somehow just passing first letter into structure -- I've tried just doing {class} and get (error -its a int)
        uni_t uni_array1 = {{*class}, {*name}, (*array[count-1]) - '0'};
        uni_array[count2] = uni_array1;

        //This is just giving me one char. 
        printf("Value of structure class: %s\n", (*(uni_array + count2)).classes); 
        count2++;
    }
}
```

I'm currently using VIM editor with a gcc compiler on a Fedora OS. I have tried declaring locations in memory with multiple different fashions, I've talked to 3 of the teacher assistants, however, none of us could figure out why it wasn't passing the whole string, but just the first char of the string. A hint toward getting the whole string into the data-structure would be appreciated (something wrong with declaration of structure line)? Thanks.

Comment: You're not using `strtok()` correctly. The first call should pass `bp`, all the rest should pass `NULL`, which means to get the next token in the same string. And copying `c` to `bp` doesn't make a copy of the string, so `strtok()` will still mess it up.

Comment: You say that your function takes in a file, but it takes a `char *` argument and reads from `stdin`, not a file. It's not clear why the function needs that argument.

Comment: `char *array[5000]` seems like like overkill. The line is at most 79 characters long, so it can't have more than 39 words in it.

Comment: Yes everything you say is helpful - thank you. But I don't see how I'm using strtok() wrong still? The first argument being passed into strtok() is the first line of file and then i set bp to null so it is null for the rest of the words in the line. (as its in a while loop)

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongist other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation funtions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the posted code.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.I.E. 80, 300, 5000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: Regarding: `while(1) {
            cp = strtok(bp, " \n");
            bp = NULL;
            if (cp == NULL){
                break;
            }
            array[count] = cp;
            count++;
        }`   this would be much better written as:  `cp = strtok(bp, " \n");
        while( cp )
        {
            strcpy( array[count], cp );
            count++;
            cp = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
        }`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 1 ; i < count-1; ++i){
            strcat(name, array[i]);
            strcat(name, " ");
        }`  when the `name[]` contains more than 79 characters (need room for trailing NUL byte) then the buffer is overflowed.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Note: the char * bp already points to an unmodified version of the line read from the input file.  so why not just use that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy strings in C with an assignment operator `=`. Beside that, as noted in previous answer you incorrectly use [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html).

As your input data can have spaces in second element, consider using [`strchr()` and `strrchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) functions to tokenize input data instead `strtok()`.

```
CSCI112 Programming with C 3
^      ^                  ^ ^
|      |                  | |
c      |                  | c + strlen(c)
      strchr()           strrchr()
```

---

This might be an overkill, but you might want to enter world of dynamic memory allocation and use [`strndup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) to copy strings. This would require you to change the structure to:

```
typedef struct {
    char *classes;
    char *names;
    int credits;
} uni_t;
```

Dynamically allocated memory should be freed when no longer used.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't assign an array or string to another in C:

```
char name[64] = "Joel Spolsky";
name = "Jeff Atwood"; // Error: "assignment to expression with array type"
```

The first line is called an initialization, and is the only situation where you can assign to an array or string. If you want to assign something else again, you have to use one of these:

```
char name[64] = "Joel Spolsky";
char new_name[64] = "Jeff Atwood";

strcpy(name, "Jeff Atwood"); // Susceptible to buffer overflows

memcpy(name, new_name, 64); // 3rd argument is number of bytes to copy

name[0] = '\0';
strncat(name, new_name, 63); // 3rd argument is max number of chars to copy
```

If you don't like the functions above, you can also use a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    name[i] = new_name[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. can hold up to 300 `struct UNIT` records
4. assumes no line in the input file is longer than 80 characters
5. assumes each line is formatted as 'classID' 'className' 'classCredits'
6. separates the struct definition from the 'typedef' for that struct
7. fixes several logic errors
8. incorporates most of the comments to the OPs question.
9. checks to avoid overflowing the record buffer (uni_array[])
10. added a 'tagname' to the struct definition to make it easy to view the individual fields in a debugger
11. used `strdup()` so each field in the array: `uni_array[]` would not be pointing to the same input buffer

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define CLASS_ID_LEN 8
#define MAX_CLASS_NAME_LEN 80

#define MAX_UNITS  300
#define MAX_ARRAY_POINTERS  80
#define MAX_INPUT_LEN 80

struct UNIT
{
    char classID[ CLASS_ID_LEN +1 ];
    char className[ MAX_CLASS_NAME_LEN +1 ];
    int credits;
};
typedef struct UNIT unit;


void process_file( void );

int main( void )
{
    process_file();
    return (0);
}


void process_file()
{
    //Declare variables
    char *array[ MAX_ARRAY_POINTERS ];
    int   count2 = 0;
    unit  uni_array[ MAX_UNITS ];
    char  inputBuf[ MAX_INPUT_LEN +2 ];

    //Read in file line by line
    while ( count2 < MAX_UNITS && fgets( inputBuf, sizeof( inputBuf ), stdin ) )
    {
        size_t count = 0;

        //Separate each word on input line into an array
        char *token = strtok( inputBuf, " \n" );
        while( token )
        {
            array[count] = strdup( token );
            count++;
            token = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
        }

        //Structure declaration, clearing, setting of fields
        unit uni_array1;
        memset( &uni_array1, '\0', sizeof( unit ) );

        strcpy( uni_array1.classID, array[0] );

        for ( size_t i = 1; i < (count-2); i++ )
        {
            strcat( uni_array1.className, array[i] );
        }

        uni_array1.credits = atoi( array[count-1] );


        // echo some values for checking
        printf( "Class: %s\n", uni_array1.classID );
        printf( "Value of structure class: %s\n", uni_array1.className );

        // copy record to array of records
        memcpy( &(uni_array[count2]), &uni_array1, sizeof( unit ) );


        // cleanup before reading next input data
        for( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            free( array[i] );
        }

        // track how many records read
        count2++;
    }
}
```